# Increasing ulimit stack size benefits?

Tags: memory, performance, limit

Hello I'm new in Linux and at my work I have a server that runs a banking software.

The company that made the software said that the stack size should be set to unlimited.
Does this make the software have a better performance if I set it to unlimited?

For now it is 10240 and the end of day rollover process takes like two hours and a half to finish and I'm trying to find a way to make it shorter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, stack size should not affect speed. If you don't have enough you crash with a stack overflow error. More stack usually should not affect performance.

Comment: I see. Can you suggest something from the ulimit that can increase performance ?

Comment: `ulimit` is about limiting access to resources so you're not going to increase performance. At most you're going to stop some other workload from taking resources away from the workload you care about. Think about it as a containment mechanism for resource hogs.

Comment: If the address space is limited, you may see if raising this limit increases speed as some applications cache higher level objects in memory. That would depend on the application, though. You might also look into tuning I/O or networking depending on whether it seems to be I/O or network-bound. If it's CPU bound there's not much to do except get competing processes out of the way and try to configure the application so it has less work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the stack size just gives a large stack for a program to run. It doesn't really make the program run fast, but prevents the program from running out of stack space and crashing. If you have too many local variables and data (which are stored on the stack), and a lot of recursion (or a long chain of calls), the stack usage is going to be high.